# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookmarksController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

i am learning Ruby on Rails and i have a problem:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookmarksController#show
Couldn't find Bookmark with 'id'=

**Controller:**

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @bookmarks = Bookmark.all
    end
    def show
      @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
    end

    def new
    end
end
```

**View:**

```
<h2>Detail zum Favorit</h2>

<p>Titel: <%= h @bookmark.title %></p>

<p>URL: <%= h @bookmark.url %></p>

<p>Kommentar: <%= h @bookmark.comment %></p>

<p>Erstellt am: <%= @bookmark.created_at %></p>

<p>Geändert am: <%= @bookmark.updated_at %></p>
```

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "bookmarks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.text     "comment"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'bookmarks/index'
  get 'bookmarks/edit'
  get 'bookmarks/new'
  get 'bookmarks/show'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".
    resources :bookmarks
```

**URL:**

```
http://localhost:3000/bookmarks/show
```

I followed this instruction:
http://openbook.galileo-press.de/ruby_on_rails/ruby_on_rails_05_004.htm#mj035976f94f0c66066b0f06b2ffe8e16e

Comment: You are following an old tutorial or document for rails. With rails you should try to match your version to the tutorial version. And look for. A newer one that is closer to te latest versions as a decent amount has changed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the 4 `get` paths in `routes.rb`, the `resources` method adds 7 basic REST actions and URLs, you can see them if you call `rake routes` from your terminal.

The right URL is `/bookmarks/<id>` and the based upon this ID, the record will be loaded in the controller.

Comment: Ok i deleted the 4 get paths in routes.rb - did i have to set the right URL anywhere?

Comment: No, it was automatically added by `resource :bookmarks`, as I've written before.

Answer (score 0):

index.html must look like

```
<h2>Detail zum Favorit</h2>

<% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>

    <p>Titel: <%= h bookmark.title %></p>

    <p>URL: <%= h bookmark.url %></p>

    <p>Kommentar: <%= h bookmark.comment %></p>

    <p>Erstellt am: <%= bookmark.created_at %></p>

    <p>Geändert am: <%= bookmark.updated_at %></p>

    <%= link_to 'Show', bookmark_path(bookmark.id) %>

<% end %>
```

`@bookmarks` is a collection of objects hence loop through, to display the objects in the Array.

Have this in your routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bookmarks
  ........
end
```

This automatically generates basic 7 restful URL's for **Bookmark** check by running `rake routes`

Comment: My index.html looked different and it works fine. i think show.html is the problem. The routes.rb looked now like you described and it doesnt work.

Comment: Exactly the same as in the description. The console: Started GET "/bookmarks/show" for ::1 at 2015-01-11 15:58:43 +0100
Processing by BookmarksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"show"}
  Bookmark Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

Comment: how does your link look ? are you passing the object?

Comment: what is the output of `rake routes`? Could you post it in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all follow the right tutorial to learn rails, I will recommend to use this one [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html][1]

Second thing the issue is because of routes you defined in `routes.rb`

you don't need to define these routes -

```
get 'bookmarks/index'
get 'bookmarks/edit'
get 'bookmarks/new'
get 'bookmarks/show'
```

because rails generates 7 basic routes automatically. so first of all remove these 4 routes from your `routes.rb`

This is enough in your route file to generates 7 basic routes for `bookmarks` . -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :bookmarks
  ........
end
```